# Extracting all List Content from multiple Lists from a Site Collection from a SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i am a Sharepoint administrator of a small farm. One of our solution provider has created a huge amount of WebSites at an SharePoint 2010 that have a hierachialy order. And every WebSite has a Custom list with the name "User. Now i want to extract from every WebSite this list into one csv file. The best would be to also extract the Name of the WebSite directly as a new column.

I understand that i have to use the SPSiteDataQuery Class but i am new to developing for sharepoint so i am not sure where to start. Also i would like to have it to run weekly, like some kind of service.

I should note that i have some knowledge in c#

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

MG,

Using SharePoint Timer Job you can execute you code weekly base then fetch User data from all webs.

Comment: Hello, i found this and i think it solves my problem regarding the repetition of the task: http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/